# Edit a specific object property keeping the same object structure

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

Let's say I have this object:

```
a = {
  key1: {
    name: 'a',
    import: 1234.7896,
    discount: 122.34553
  }
  key2: {
    name: 'b'
    import: 8976.09998,
    discount: 12.890999
  }  
}
```

and I have a function which format the number in some way and returning a string. Applying that function I want an object like this:

```
result = {
  key1: {
    name: 'a'
    import: '1,234.78'
    discount: '122.33'
  }
  key2: {
    name: 'b'
    import: '8,976.09'
    discount: '12.89'
  }  
}
```

So, my goal is to take all the properties which contains numbers and format them.
How can I iterate the object to edit just the properties which contains a number and return another object with the same key and different numeric properties?

Comment: Can you include a sample of the desired output (and maybe an attempt what you've tried so far)?

Comment: I was trying using Object.keys(a).map((key) => {Object.keys(a[key].map((key2)=> ...))})
And then I got lost among the keys.
I'm pretty sure there is a way to make it using Object.keys or Object.entries

Answer (score 0):

The natural approach to this task is recursion.  Below I've assumed you have a `format` function that formats a number into a string as you desire, and defined `recurseFormat` to recurse through object values, looking for values of type `"number"` to run `format` on.  You might need to modify the `typeof value === 'object'` test to suite your needs for when to recurse.

```js
function format(number) {
  ...
}
function recurseFormat(object) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      object[key] = format(value)
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      recurseFormat(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this code modifies your object in place.  If you want to deep copy your object at the same time, that can be done with a similar recursive approach; let me know and I can try writing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement recursion which will work for nested object as well. Something like this:

```js
const convertToString=obj=>{
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v])=>[k, typeof v=="object" ? convertToString(v) : v.toLocaleString()]))
};

const a = { key1: { name: 'a', import: 1234.7896, discount: 122.34553 }, key2: { name: 'b', import: 8976.09998, discount: 12.890999 } };

console.log(convertToString(a));
```